# How to create a grouped column chart with Protovis

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, protovis

I'm trying to create a graph using Protovis. This is an image of how I want to graph to look like. 
https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/revenue-graph.png?w=5fd1840d

Here's how far I have come based on code from the protovis site. 
http://jsfiddle.net/psivadasan/RKTZL/

I'm not sure how to add legends and a title for the graph. The graph also doesn't render in IE9.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Two issues here: 1) your image link doesn't seem to work (403 forbidden error), and 2) I'm not seeing anything rendered in your fiddle on Chrome. There are much easier ways to set up Protovis in jsFiddle - see http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/NY7G3/

Comment: In most cases you should avoid using a grouped column chart. There are better ways of representing the data, depending on the message you want to get across. Look into 'multiples' and slopegraphs for starters.